# 3dsmax maxscript: How do I get an array/list of verts in the order I selected them?

Tags: python, selection, 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm writing a tool for 3dsmax that requires a user to get selected vertices in the order they were selected in an array, but so far passing this returns vertices in their created order:

```
sel = getCurrentSeletion()
selvets = vsel[1].selectedVerts
```

How would I get selected vertices in the order I selected them in 3ds max, using maxscript?

If there is no way in maxscript, is there a way to do that in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about the positions of the verts, you can use `pickPoint` function instead. Otherwise make a callback that updates on selection change and record the differences. An example would be (if your current node is Editable poly):

```
try destroyDialog selectVerts catch()
rollout selectVerts ""
(
    local verts, currentSel

    fn collectVerts event nodes =
    (
        local sel = polyop.getVertSelection $
        local newVerts = sel - currentSel
        local removedVerts = currentSel - sel

        for v in removedVerts do if (local index = findItem verts v) > 0 do deleteItem verts index
        for v in newVerts do append verts v
        currentSel = sel
    )

    local callback = nodeEventCallback mouseUp:on enabled:off subobjectSelectionChanged:collectVerts

    checkButton chbSwitchCallback "Select verts"

    on chbSwitchCallback changed state do
    (
        if state and isKindOf $ Editable_Poly then
        (
            verts = #()
            currentSel = polyop.getVertSelection $
            callback.enabled = on
        )
        else
        (
            callback.enabled = off
            print verts #noMap
        )
    )
)
createDialog selectVerts
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this works quite well for what I needed. (And you were faster and more helpful than Autodesk)